# NodeJS how do I get body of a request returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, rest

I have the following function in NodeJS that I use to make GET and POST calls to REST APIs

```
function httpRequest(options, postData) {      
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const https = require('https');
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        // reject on bad status
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
            console.log('Bad status code '+res.statusCode+' '+res.statusMessage);
            reject(new Error(res.statusMessage));
        }else{
          var body = [];
          res.on('data', function(chunk) {
              body.push(chunk);
          });
          res.on('end', function() {
              resolve(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
          });
        }
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + err.message);
      reject(err);
    });
    if (postData) {
      req.write(postData);
    }
    req.end();
  });
}
```

The calls may result in a 400 Bad Request or some other error, and there is message in the returned Body. I cannot figure out how to read this body message. The variable res does not contain any property with body data and the res.on('data' event is never called so I could read  the body message.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to move a request status verification to the `end` event handler:

```
const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    const body = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        const bodyString = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
            console.log(bodyString);
            reject(new Error(res.statusMessage));
        } else {
            resolve(bodyString);
        }
    });
});
```